# Error-checking macro to jump to specified label given a failing statement

Tags: c, error-handling, macros

I'm starting a new C projet and I want to have the cleanest and shortest error checking code possible.

To that aim, I often use two things :

1. functions return `0`, `false` or `NULL` on error
2. I try to use small functions with one cleanup label "fail" or "error"

So I thought about using a macro to simplify the code even more. If I choose to use it, this pattern will appear **in almost every function** so I expect that people reading the code **will become accustomed to it very quickly**.

So, is it a viable solution ? Here is an example snippet :

```
#define try( stmt , error_label ) if (!(stmt)) { goto error_label; }

// this function creates a new image database
ImageDatabase*
db_create(uint32_t max_images,
          struct resolution resolutions[NB_RESOLUTIONS])
{
    ImageDatabase* db;
    try( db = allocate_empty_db(), error);
    memcpy(db->resolutions, resolutions, NB_RESOLUTIONS * sizeof(struct resolution));
    db->max_nb_images = max_images;
    try( db->metadatas = calloc(max_images, sizeof(struct metadata)) , error);
    try( finalize_creation(db) , error);
    return db;

error:
    free(db->metadatas);
    free(db);
    return NULL;
}
```

---

EDIT: Here is an alternative without the `try` macro... but it's not as pretty. Also note that in this example the code is simple enough to avoid a goto, but it's not always the case.

```
ImageDatabase*
db_create(uint32_t max_images,
          struct resolution resolutions[NB_RESOLUTIONS])
{
    ImageDatabase* db = allocate_empty_db();
    if (db) {
        memcpy(db->resolutions, resolutions, NB_RESOLUTIONS * sizeof(struct resolution));
        db->max_nb_images = max_images;
        db->metadatas = calloc(max_images, sizeof(struct metadata)) , error);
        if (db->metadata == NULL
           || !finalize_creation(db)) 
        {
            free(db->metadatas);
            free(db);
            db = NULL;
        }
    }
    return db;
}
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/25187/23788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### NULL dereference

If `allocate_empty_db()` returns NULL, it will jump to the error handling code, which will cause a NULL dereference when it tries to `free(db->metadatas)`.  You will need to guard that line like this:

```
if (db)
    free(db->metadatas);
```

#### The macro

I'm not exactly a fan of the macro.  First, calling it `try` makes me think your code is java, and then when I realize it isn't, I'm more confused.  Second, if your label is always going to be the same in every function, then you can omit the second argument of the macro and just hardcode it to `goto error`.  That way the macro can look smaller and the reader doesn't have to parse the extra comma and argument (which look like part of the body you are try-ing).

Also, the macro should be a `do while` instead of an `if`.  You could get in trouble with code like this:

```
if (condition)
    try(foo(), error);
else
    bar();
```

Here, your macro will cause the above to expand to:

```
if (condition)
    if (!foo()) { goto error; };
else
    bar();
```

Which is actually a syntax error because of the extra semicolon but is also close to making the `else` pair with the wrong `if`.  The macro should look like this instead:

```
#define try( stmt , error_label )              \
        do {                                   \
            if (!(stmt)) { goto error_label; } \
        } while(0)
```

This `do while(0)` construction is a common trick when writing C macros.  It allows a multi-statement macro to be used in an `if` statement like the one in my example.  See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Your code using a macro just doesn't look like C, whereas the code it replaces does. And while you think your code looks prettier, many will disagree. Error handling in C is difficult and messy. But people expect to see it spelled out not hidden away.

So I'd say if you are writing this project with other people, don't use this macro. It will wind-up many programmers (as do personalized indenting styles and other non-standard approaches) and I don't think it will really make life easier.